# PHP if statement conundrum

Tags: php, arrays

First of all, I understand why this is not working, but am not 100% sure on a decent way to fix it within my scenario.

I have 2 arrays, male genetics and female genetics. There's a loop that runs through and pairs them together, here's an example:

`'Bell-Albino' => 'Bb'`

Problem is, I need to do something like this:

```
if($gene != 'BB' || $gene != 'RR' || $gene != 'TT'){
    echo 'Recessive Albino';
}
```

The conundrum is, if the `$gene` is `BB` for example, this will always return `'recessive albino'` because the other 2 `or` statements are being matched.

The array has many key's and this code only needs to run on the above values, hence why I can't do a simple check on if they value is upper case. `EE` isn't an albino strain, only `BB, RR and TT` are.

I *could* do this as an `elseif()` condition but it would add an extra 10 lines or so and not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your example? I feel like this probably has a simple solution however I'm not 100% sure what you're after.

Comment: Exactly what i want form OP.

Comment: Could you post your array's???

Comment: Shouldn't you just replace `||` with `&&` ?

Comment: No because they won't all be set at the same time. They can only really carry one recessive trait so setting it to check if it has one AND another AND another is the same issue as OR. 

@Ankh In theory I can do an `elseif` condition but was hoping there might be a way to do it without writing an extra 10 lines of code or so

Comment: I can't really follow you, to be honest. Of course they're no all set at the same time which is exactly the reason why you need `&&` instead of `||` when using negative condition checks. Can you give an example of the `elseif` construct, then we can see how it can be simplified.

Comment: Yeah that might work, will try a bit later on

Comment: Just going to blame my above comment on tiredness. Totally works, sorry haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is slightly confusing. But let me try to guess.

I think you are wanting to write something like this

```
$gene = 'Bb';
if (!in_array($gene, ['BB', 'RR', 'TT'])) {
    echo 'Recessive Albino'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Non Recessive Albino'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

If `$gene` is not in the given list we have recessive albino. Else we have may be non recessive albino.

Initially I suggested to use `strtoupper` but it seems like this is wrong and the case do make difference.

Comment: The string is output as `Bb` from using the parental genes. It takes `B` from the male and `b` from the female for example and then throws out `Bb`. So technically it's not in an array. This script is building a punnet square for calculating genetics so it's quite difficult to explain haha

Comment: Though as I re read your example this might work how I want, misread it the first time! I'll give it a go and let you know

Comment: Thank you, nice clean way :)